# Cannot pair Cochlear implant hearing device to Apple Watch

Tags: bluetooth, apple-watch, headphones, accessibility

I am using a Series 5 Apple watch with the newest iOS, 6.1. I have a Nucleus 7 Cochlear implant sound processor which pairs fine with my iPhone. However, the Apple Watch cannot find my hearing aid. When I try to pair, the watch just keeps searching for devices.

Likely this is related to this post: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8566538?answerId=33972634022#33972634022. I tried following the advice in the reply, but it was not very applicable and did not help at all.

Has anyone had success pairing a hearing device with an Apple Watch?

Comment: Can your Nucleus 7 pair to multiple devices or just a single device?

Comment: Multiple devices

Comment: Can you pair any other Bluetooth devices to your Apple Watch?

Comment: I don't really have any other Bluetooth devices unfortunately

Comment: I imagined that could be the case. As much of a pain that it is, have you tried factory resetting your Apple Watch and tried pairing after that?

Comment: No, but I would like to avoid that. I guess we'll wait and see if anyone else has a solution.